# Permission denied for ASP.NET app to access database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssms, sitefinity

I have a Sitefinity ASP.NET web site which has a database `Db1`. I have the database attached to SQL Server Management Studio.

When I run the ASP.NET application, it doesn't seem to have permission to access the database. Sitefinity fails to connect to the existing db, then tries to create a new db, which it throws this error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

The connection string is:

```
<add connectionString="data source=localhost\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=Db1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" dbType="MsSql" name="Sitefinity" />
```

In SQL Management Studio, I connect to the localhost\SQLEXPRESS instance using Windows Authentication.

I think the problem is, I need to give the ASP.NET process user, permission to access the database `Db1`. Where can I find this user and how can I give permission?

I'm also unsure if the app should be using a proper SQL Server user to connect instead of Windows Authentication.

Comment: I'd personally create a specific authentication for your application and specify that in your connection string.  If and when you move to different environments such as dev, qa, production or dr and the database isn't local you'll need to use something other than integrated anyway.

Comment: @RobA how can I create an auth for my app? I have tried the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666828/create-a-new-db-user-in-sql-server-2005 but the query just sits there saying "debugging query" until I stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct, and portable/deployable, solution, is to switch to SQL Server Authentication.

In SSMS, expand the security tab for the *server*, and add a user with a suitable name and password. Be sure to uncheck the "must change password at next logon" checkbox.

Then, expand the security tab for the *database*, add the user, and add it to whatever roles are necessary. For debugging you may just want to add it to the db owner role.

This is helpful because all of the relevant settings are stored within your app config and the database itself, making deployent a cinch, and you don't need to worry about keeping application user accounts updated when passwords expire, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS, find the app pool for your web site, and set the credentials to the windows account you want to use to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1):

ypu are using your AD user on your connection string, see the Integrated Security=SSPI item? When true, it means that the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

Are you sure your user has permission to create databases on that instnace?

Comment: With my windows user account (Administrator), I can login to SQLServer and create/read/modify databases through Management Studio, so does that mean I am OK to use integrated security on the connection string?

Comment: is Administrator the name of the account? How do you connect to your windows box? When connecting to sql server you shouldt have to type any password (you should use the windows authentication mode). 
there is also the UAC issue, I imagine yo uare on W7? Take a look at this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx

Comment: +1 thanks for the help, I got it working with SQL Server Auth instead of Windows.

Comment: oh yes, thats a good option too. I thought you didn't want to use it