# Create a user with permissions for only 1 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the way via a script to add a user to a database with permissions of select, insert, update and delete but only have access to that one database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE USER [user] FOR LOGIN [user]
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'your_db'
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'your_db'
GO
```

[Create a new db user in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666828/create-a-new-db-user-in-sql-server-2005)